# Word for being disgusted by but unable to stop looking at something

Tags: single-word-requests

This seems to be a common phenomenon — lots of people report being unable to avert their eyes from a wound or dead body or even the mess after they blow their nose! But is there a single word for it? I found some related terms like "rubbernecking", but that seems to be the act of looking rather than the urge to look (or inability to look away).

Comment: "***Hathos*** is the attraction to something you really can’t stand; it’s the compulsion of revulsion." From [this source](http://dish.andrewsullivan.com/2013/12/18/christmas-hathos-watch-2/).

Comment: It may be a fine distinction, but *hathos* is *[pleasure derived from loathing](http://www.wordspy.com/words/hathos.asp)*, not fascination with loathsome things— or at least, things which are not viscerally loathsome to most people.

Comment: That's another interpretation, certainly. But the fact that somebody says that's what it is does not mean that everybody knows, cares, or uses it that way. There is no definitive meaning that is attached to a word; only a history of its use.

Comment: I must agree with @choster here. I have seen and heard ‘hathos’ used quite a lot, and it has always been in the sense of ‘love to hate’. I don't recall ever seeing or hearing it used for something unpleasant that you, unwillingly, cannot avert your eyes from. (I have also seen it used as a term to specifically denote the act of hating _The Three Musketeers_, but that's a pun of a pun—hardly its basic sense.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One might exhibit *morbidity*, or possess a *morbid curiosity*, *morbid fixation*, or *morbid fascination* with such things:

> [morbid](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/morbid), *adj.*: 1. having or expressing a strong interest in sad or unpleasant things, especially disease or death

Note that *morbidity* means something quite different in medical jargon.

Comment: +1 for ***morbid fascination***. By far the most common term I've heard for this phenomenon.

Comment: Not sure about *morbid* for "the mess after they blow their nose"! But [*fascination*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=fascinate&allowed_in_frame=0) is definitely right.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, I think. But like Andrew Leacch I wonder what kind of disgust it applies to - I don't think it applies to the nasal example, even though that seems to be an instance of the same "compulsion of disgust" phenomenon.

Answer (score 4):

Consider **[train wreck](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/train-wreck?q=train%20wreck)**

> a chaotic or disastrous situation that holds a peculiar fascination for observers

Comment: I guess this is related to "rubbernecking", although that seems more used for motorists passing a traffic accident.

Answer (score 3):

[**compelled**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compel): driven or urged forcefully or irresistibly, often [against one's will](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/compel).

> For me, once you're a painter, you're constantly compelled to look at the world as a potential subject for painting.
>
> O accursed hunger of gold, to what dost thou not compel human hearts! - Virgil