# Single word that combines the meaning of fear and fascination?

Tags: single-word-requests

I guess it should be something like *awe* but instead of the *respect* component it has *fear*. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but this question discusses a mix of fascination and hate, which might have some relevant words: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265385/single-word-that-combines-the-meaning-of-fascination-and-hate

Answer (score 1):

***Awe*** is actually the best you've got. Dictionaries actually point out that *fear* is a meaning included in *awe*:

> a feeling of great ***respect*** sometimes mixed with ***fear*** or ***surprise***:
>
> - As children we were rather in ***awe*** of our grandfather. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/awe))

> an emotion variously combining ***dread***, ***veneration***, and ***wonder*** that is inspired by authority or by the sacred or sublime
>
> - stood in awe of the king ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awe))

> Awe is the feeling of *respect* and *amazement* that you have when you are faced with something *wonderful* and often ***rather frightening***.
>
> - She filled me with a sense of ***awe***. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/awe))

In fact the first two synonyms of *awe* suggested by Collins are ***wonder*** and ***fear***.

Comment: Should we be answering questions where OP hasn't supplied obvious research themself?

Comment: I've seen many users do that, but ok, maybe it's not good policy. The OP did explain clearly the word they are looking for and I was drawn to answer :)